# Firebase Cloud Firestore: where().onSnapshot to Subcollection

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I’m making Javascript below.
The entire system consists of HTML, Javascript and Python. they send/receive/show some data.

when to press generateBtn(), Form data on HTML is sent to Javascript and Python.
Javascript waits data processing of Python ( waitUpdate() ). After that, Javascript shows the data python sent ( generateProfile() ).

So far, waitUpdate() doesn’t work.
when to start “const waitUpdate = async function(user_uid) {”, it doesn’t get into “db.collection(“users”)…where(“generate_flag”, “==”, true).onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {”. And it shows console.log('Flag : ’ + flag); (this shows Flag: true) right before sleep(1000);. So it gets into infinity loop shows “Flag: true”.

When to confirm generate_flag in CloudFirestore account, it shows true. So I thought
it’s got into “.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {”. But actually It’s not, somehow I mentioned above.

Did anyone realize how to solve this issue?
I’d appreciate it, if you would tell me the way to solve it.
Thank you.

```
function generateBtn() {

  var user_uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
  //console.log("In createCloze() : user_uid : " + user_uid);

  const waitUpdate = async function(user_uid) {
    let flag
    flag = true

    while(flag){
      //console.log("while() in waitUpdate() : user_uid = " + user_uid); //Okay.
      db.collection("users").doc(user_uid).collection("logdata").where("generate_flag", "==", true)
          .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
              console.log("In .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) =>");//It's never been through here so far.
              querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                  console.log("In querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>");
                  if(doc.data().mypythonfeedback_flag == false){
                    flag = false;
                    //console.log('Flag : ' + flag + ' in if(doc.data().mypythonfeedback_flag == false)');
                  }
              }); //querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          }); //.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {

      console.log('Flag : ' + flag);
      sleep(1000);
    } //while(flag){
  }

  //Omitted. This shows the data.
  const generateProfile = async function(user_uid) {
    console.log('In generateProfile()');
  } //const generateProfile = async function(user_uid) {


  const processAll = async function(user_uid) {
    await waitUpdate(user_uid)
    await generateProfile(user_uid)
  }

  processAll(user_uid)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, because it may need to come from the  network. While the data is being loaded, your other code continues to execute. And then when the data is loaded, your callback is called with that data.

What this means in practice is that your `console.log('Flag : ' + flag)` runs before the `flag = false` is ever executed, so it always shows the default value. You can most easily verify this by setting breakpoints on these lines and running in a debugger, or by checking that `Flag : true` shows *before* `In querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>` in your output.

The simplest solution for this is to put the code that needs the flag *into* the callback that is called when the data is loaded, so like this:

```
db.collection("users").doc(user_uid).collection("logdata").where("generate_flag", "==", true)
   .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
       querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
           if(doc.data().mypythonfeedback_flag == false){
             flag = false;
           }
       }); //querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       console.log('Flag : ' + flag); // 
   });
```

---

To allow the caller to `await` until the flag becomes false, you can return a custom promise:

```
const waitUpdate = async function(user_uid) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let flag
    flag = true

    db.collection("users").doc(user_uid).collection("logdata").where("generate_flag", "==", true)
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          if(doc.data().mypythonfeedback_flag == false){
            flag = false;
            resolve();
          }
        });
      });
  })
}
```

As you'll see, we've removed the loop here - and instead call `resolve()` (which then triggers the `await`) from *within* the callback that listens for updates from the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mr. Puffelen. Your code saved my day.